# Habilitar delete cascade em apenas uma lista

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho meu *model* que possui várias listas. Por exemplo:

```
public class Funcionario
{
   public ICollection<FuncionarioNotificacao> Notificacoes {get;set;}
   public ICollection<FuncionarioExame> Exames {get;set;}

}
```

Vejamos que no *model* acima, eu tenho referência de funcionário a essa lista de notificações e de exames.

Eu gostaria de fazer o *cascade* apenas na lista de notificação. Ou seja, quando eu for deletar o funcionário, se ele tiver apenas vínculo com notificações, ele remove tudo, se ele tiver alguma referencia de Exames, virá a *exception*.

Comment: O resto do sistema vai ou não cascatear por padrão?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Não, apenas essa lista desse model, demais models não terão cascade habilitado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WillCascadeOnDelete()` definido com `false` deve resolver:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Funcionario>().
      HasMany(f => f.Notificacoes).
      WithRequired(n => n.Funcionario).
      HasForeignKey(n => n.FuncionarioId).
      WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```